# jQuery (1.8) - Cancelling remaining event chain

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two `submit` handlers, which are added in the following order:

This one is added first, in the page's particular code:

```
function validateOnSubmit() {
    //sacar el rojo de textfield de producto
    console.log("pre-submit");
    if (currentRestrictions == null) {
        //debe seleccionar un producto
        $("#invalidProductDialog").dialog("open");
        return false;
    } else if (!currentRestrictions.allows($("#largo").val(), $("#ancho").val(), $("#calibre").val())) {
        //hay un error de validacion
        $("#invalidDimensionsDialog").dialog("open");
        return false;
    }
}
```

This one is added later, in page's layout (I'm using Yii Framework, althought it's irrelevant to the question):

```
$("form:not(.allow-double-post)").submit(function () {
      console.log("check double post...");
      if($(this).data("alreadyInput")){
            return false;
      } else {
            $(this).data("alreadyInput", true);
            // regular checks and submit the form here
            return true;
      }
});
```

I tested if they're run in order (consider the two message log instructions there), and they're running in the right order (i.e. the validateOnSubmit first, and the DoublePost checker later).

However I expect the `return false` in the validateOnSubmit cut the event chain (i.e. the `validateOnSubmit` is run and after returning false the double post checker is not run), but after the `return false` (whichever of the two reasons in the `validateOnSubmit` function) the double-post checker handler is run. I thought that in jquery 1.8 having a `return false` would cut the events chain.

**Q**: How can I cut the events chain when one of the two conditions occur? i.e. conditions where, currently, a `return false` is executed on `validateOnSubmit`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that jQuery doesn't cut the events chain by reaching a `return false`. The expected solution should be:

```
function eventHandler(e) {
    //...
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
    //...
}
```

adding the `stopImmediatePropagation` call **before** the `return false` so it remains consistent.

(Another tumbleweed here?)